# Is my training regime going to build muscle mass?

Tags: strength-training, push-ups, pull-ups, chin-ups, sprinting

I'm aiming to build muscle mass by going to the outdoor gym in my area. This is the routine I've been doing for the last few months

**Saturday**

- 5 sets of 10 pull ups
- 5 sets of 25 push ups

**Sunday**

- 5 sets of 10 chin ups
- 5 sets of 100 sit ups

**Tuesday**

- 5 sprints of 200 metres

About me: Male, 79 kg, 182 cm tall, lean physique

My question is: will this routine add muscle mass?

Comment: If you want to train like this look into calisthenics. Check some people who do it, they look pretty good.

Comment: The number of sets, reps, and days is just one factor in the process of building muscle mass.  There's also genetics, recovery, and nutrition to name a few.  As written, your question will receive opinions and/or suggestions.  There's no way for anyone to predict your success at building mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General rules of strength/muscle volume (not endurance):

1. Don't work the same muscles heavily on consecutive days.
2. If you can do more than 15 reps in a set, the load is too light.

Your pull ups/chin ups goes against #1, skip one of them or move chin ups to tuesday. How many can you do in one set? Try adding some weight somehow.

The sit ups and push ups go against #2. Try hanging leg raises for your abs instead. There is no reason to do more sit ups than you would other exercises. The abs are not different from other muscles in that sense.

There are loads of variants of pushups you can do that will be tougher and thus lower your rep count. Google it.

Since you are pretty fit, muscle ups can be something to look into.

Comment: No workout is complete without squats. If you don't have a barbell, then buy dumbbell / kettlebell for weighted squats. If you want bodyweight only, then try pistol squats. And going into more detail on push ups, I'd suggest trying incline, "clapping," or one-handed to get the higher intensity and lower volume.